# How to handle Unity Component errors when switching routes in Next.js with React-Unity-Webgl?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, unity-webgl

react-unity-webgl component giving a bunch of errors when switching routes in Nextjs/React

So I have this Unity Component in my javascript in the pages directory (shouldn't be there but left it there for now for importing easily) and whenever I switch to another page via a route I get a bunch of errors because the html canvas isn't being recognized, here's my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { Unity, UnityContext, useUnityContext } from "react-unity-webgl";
// ['An error occurred running the Unity content on this page.', 'The error was:', 'TypeError: canvas is null']
const width = 850;
const height = 562.5;
function UnityComponent() {
  const { unityProvider, isLoaded, loadingProgression } = useUnityContext({
    loaderUrl: "Juego/Build/temp.loader.js",
    dataUrl: "Juego/Build/temp.data",
    frameworkUrl: "Juego/Build/temp.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "Juego/Build/temp.wasm",
  });


  // We'll use a state to store the device pixel ratio.
  const [devicePixelRatio, setDevicePixelRatio] = useState(
    window.devicePixelRatio
  );

  const handleChangePixelRatio = useCallback(
    function () {
      // A function which will update the device pixel ratio of the Unity
      // Application to match the device pixel ratio of the browser.
      const updateDevicePixelRatio = function () {
        setDevicePixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      };
      // A media matcher which watches for changes in the device pixel ratio.
      const mediaMatcher = window.matchMedia(
        `screen and (resolution: ${devicePixelRatio}dppx)`
      );
      // Adding an event listener to the media matcher which will update the
      // device pixel ratio of the Unity Application when the device pixel
      // ratio changes.
      mediaMatcher.addEventListener("change", updateDevicePixelRatio);
      return function () {
        // Removing the event listener when the component unmounts.
        mediaMatcher.removeEventListener("change", updateDevicePixelRatio);
      };
    },
    [devicePixelRatio]
  );
  const loadingPercentage = Math.round(loadingProgression * 100);
  return (
    <div className="UnityComponent" style={{ width: width, height: height }}>
      {isLoaded === false && (
        // We'll conditionally render the loading overlay if the Unity
        // Application is not loaded.
        <div className="loading-overlay">
          <p>Loading... ({loadingPercentage}%)</p>
        </div>
      )}
    <Unity
      unityProvider={unityProvider}
      style={{ width: width, height: height }}
      devicePixelRatio={devicePixelRatio}
    />
    </div>

  );
}
export default UnityComponent;
```

I am using react-unity-webgl and the nextjs material-ui-kit template for the website, also using React obviously, how can I close the canavs whenever I leave? do I have to do it manually on all of my pages? if so, what does that look like?
edit: This is the error I get from nextjs:
Unhandled Runtime Error

```
TypeError: canvas is null
Call Stack
_JS_DOM_MapViewportCoordinateToElementLocalCoordinate
/Juego/Build/temp.framework.js (13:10)
<unknown>
/Juego/Build/temp.wasm:wasm-function[27381]:0x8dba38
<unknown>
/Juego/Build/temp.wasm:wasm-function[27626]:0x90b064
unityFramework/registerMouseEventCallback/mouseEventHandlerFunc/<
/Juego/Build/temp.framework.js (14:155604)
mouseEventHandlerFunc
/Juego/Build/temp.framework.js (14:155640)
jsEventHandler
/Juego/Build/temp.framework.js (14:125918)
```

and it's just that error constantly
edit 2:
I think the error occurs because I have the unity js build files statically, so they're constantly running in all parts of my website, how to stop this? can I just selectively import them to my unity page component?